# Why is code 2 not producing 10 rows of circles on my browser? But the code 1 is producing the output of 10x10 rowsxcolumns of circles with radius 10

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

The code 1 is working and giving 10 lines of circles of radius 10.

The code 2 is not working as expected, it just gives a single line of circles of radius 10.

I think the logic is correct but still there is something I am most probably missing when it comes to paper js documentation.

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Patapat Sound Project</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.18/paper-full.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
  //Code 1
  for(var x = 0; x<1000; x += 100){
   for(var y = 0; y<1000; y += 100){
    var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(x, y), 10);
    circle.fillColor = 'red';
   }
  }

  //Code 2
  var x = 10;
  var y = 10;
  while(x!=1010 && y!= 1010){
   var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(x,y), 10);
   circle.fillColor = 'orange';
   if(x==1010){
    x=10;
    y+=100;
   }
   else{
    x+=100;
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you suppose anybody will be able to help here?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the code before. But now I have included the code. Please check it and help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a problem with your logic.
The `while` loop is stopping after the 10th iteration, when x value is `1010`.
You have to increment x before doing the check in your loop.
Here is the correct code:

```
//Code 2
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
while (x != 1010 && y != 1010) {
    console.log(x, y);
    var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(x, y), 10);
    circle.fillColor = 'orange';

    // increment x every time
    x += 100;

    // then check if it will break the loop
    if (x == 1010) {
        x = 10;
        y += 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. And i understand because now it always stays x=1010 and increments y to 1010 and then it stops if not always incremented.